# Regular expression and grep not working

Tags: grep, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
([:digit:]{4})-([:digit:]{1,2})-([:digit:]{1,2})
```

It should get dates in this format:

```
2010-12-19
```

And I am using it on filenames that look like this:

```
2010-12-19-xxx-xxx-xxx.markdown
```

And, when I use it with `grep` like this:

```
echo $POST | grep -oE "([:digit:]{4})-([:digit:]{1,2})-([:digit:]{1,2})" # $POST is the filename
```

It doesn't work, I just get emptiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
echo $POST | grep -oE "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}"
```

If I try it here, I get:-

```
[andys@daedalus ~]$ echo "2010-12-19-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.markdown" | grep -oE "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}"
2010-12-19
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Andy's answer is fine, but if you want something closer to your original syntax, you could try:

`echo $POST | egrep -oE "([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{1,2})-([[:digit:]]{1,2})"`

You need egrep here for extended regular expressions, and the double brackets for character classes.

Comment: Actually, you don't need egrep if you have the `-E` option. From the grep man page: "Egrep is the same as grep -E"

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the parentheses, but you do need more square brackets. Character classes have the same characteristics as individual characters. Just as you might search for vowels like this: `[aeiou]`, or digits like this: `[0123456789]` or this: `[0-9]`, you need to enclose a class such as `[:digit:]` or `[:upper:]` in a bracket expression as well: `[[:xdigit:]]` (hex digits).

```
grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}"
```